# How to make vc-* and magit treat a symbolic link to a real file in git repo just like the original file?

Tags: magit, ediff, symbolic-links

Say, I got `~/.emacs` which is a soft link to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`(using `ln -s ~/.emacs.d/init.el ~/.emacs`) which is in a git repo, because this will make it easier to reach `init.el`, outside or inside Emacs.

When I edit the file using bookmarks(bookmark for `~/.emacs` not `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) or `C-x C-f` to `~/.emacs` directly, it will only edit the link, I use `(setq vc-follow-symlinks 'nil)` to not prompt to ask yes/no and not follow to the real file, (e.g., `M-: (buffer-file-name)` shows the `/home/user/.emacs` not `/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el`).

But sometimes I want to show the diff of this file, the `C-x v =` will not work for the link, it works in the file if I follow the link to it or open `~/.emacs,d/init.el` directly. I don't want to do `M-x magit-status` and then `~/.emacs.d/` repo and then find the init.el and then `TAB`, so is there an easy way to show the diff of the file??

Comment: I don't really understand why you disabled `vc-follow-symlinks` (or why you are maintaining the `~/.emacs` path at all, for that matter -- if it's purely for convenience, [this is probably more useful](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3171/454)?).

Comment: It's purely for convenience, no special reason. Anyway @ph0t0nix 's answer solve this problem.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Doesn't it make sense to you? I am happy to clarify. Otherwise please accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and added

```
;;; When opening a file that is a symbolic link, don't ask whether I
;;; want to follow the link. Just do it
(setq find-file-visit-truename t)
```

to my `.emacs` file.

Unfortunately I can't remember where on the web I found this, so no source credits.

Answer (score 6):

It's really quite simple; don't do that:

> I use `(setq vc-follow-symlinks nil)` to not prompt to ask yes/no and not follow to the real file

It doesn't make much sense to set this variable to `nil` and `find-file-visit-truename` to `t`. Both variables control whether Emacs should follow symlinks when visiting files. But the latter is much more aggressive. `vc-follow-symlinks` only has an effect if the file itself is a symlink, while `find-file-visit-truename` follows any symlink leading up to the file, i.e. if a ancestor directory is a symlink it follows that too.

The latter is more expensive and likely not what you want. `find-file-visit-truename` overrides whatever you have set `vc-follow-symlinks` to, and then it may also go on following other symlinks. If setting the latter to `t` gets the job done, then it's preferable to do just that.

Since you mentioned that you have set `vc-follow-symlinks` to `nil` I assume that you don't want to follow symlinks. But there's just no way around it. Like a shell an Emacs buffer has a "working directory", stored in `default-directory`. That variable is, among other things, used when running child processes (`git` in the case of VC and Magit). Without following the symlink, the process would be run with a working directory which is not inside a repository.

Or in other words:

> How to make vc-* and magit treat a soft link to a real file in git repo just like the original file?

You can't because `default-directory` is set based on the filename. Instead follow the symlink and thereby move into the repository.

Comment: @CopyChan I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ph0t0nix you might want to have a look too.