# How do I find the init.el file on windows?

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, find

I'm currently stuck with not finding the init.el file, how do I find it on Windows and how do I load it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best duplicate here is, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows/10545955#10545955 has some details on that question.

Comment: I have find it using your help but I can't save. How do I do it?

Comment: @Anon, does the `~/.emacs.d` directory exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to open my init file for editing or return its path](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/function-to-open-my-init-file-for-editing-or-return-its-path)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't save"?  What did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `M-x describe-variable user-emacs-directory` or the following commands in a emacs-lisp buffer, you will find it.

> (find-file (expand-file-name "init.el" user-emacs-directory))
>
> (describe-variable 'user-emacs-directory)

It's usually in `%AppData%\.emacs.d` but could be in `%UserProfile%\.emacs.d` if you run emacs from Start-menu.
In Powershell, `dir $env:AppData\.emacs.d`.

Load it with `(load-file (expand-file-name "init.el" user-emacs-directory))`